# How to match the right date format?

Tags: regex, string

How to match the line in the format "Test_yyyy_mm_dd.txt" using regex?

```
Test_1_1999_06_17.txt
Test_2_2003_11_20.txt
Test_2023_08_08.txt
Test_2022_08_23.txt
Test_2020_05_14.txt
```

What I want is:

```
Test_2023_08_08.txt
Test_2022_08_23.txt
Test_2020_05_14.txt
```

Comment: Simply `Test_\d\d\d\d_\d\d_\d\d\.txt`? Depending on your flavor, you can probably shorten that to `Test_\d{4}(_\d\d){2}\.txt`. Also you might need `^` and `$` anchors. What's the environment - which flavor, which programming language?

Comment: Do you mean to extract that date from file names, or validate the file names that should have no invalid date before the extension? Also, do you mean `Test` can be any *letter-only* word? If yes, can it contain any Unicode letters or only ASCII?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to validate the file names. The string "Test" is a fixed prefix.

Answer (score -2):

Simple `grep` pattern:

```
echo 'Test_1_1999_06_17.txt
Test_2_2003_11_20.txt
Test_2023_08_08.txt
Test_2022_08_23.txt
Test_2020_05_14.txt' | grep  -e '^Test_[0-9]\{4\}_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]\.txt$'
```

... produces

```
Test_2023_08_08.txt
Test_2022_08_23.txt
Test_2020_05_14.txt
```

The pattern will match lines starting with string "Test_" followed by four digits, an underscore, two digits, another underscore, two additional digits, and a ".txt" ending.

Note that this is by no means a date validation mechanism, i.e., it will also match invalid dates like "Test_0099_21_99.txt".

Hope that helps.